# General interpolation practices

Tags: interpolation, shading, animation

Say my animation scenario contains one mesh interpolating into another (possibly approximating over other meshes), using Bezier curves.

I know that for smooth surfaces, where normals can be expressed via cross product of partial derivatives, linear interpolation of vertices would induce quadratic interpolation of normals, involving some expressions with several cross product, not tied to the normals.

Is it acceptable in practice to do the same interpolation for corresponding vertex normals (linear-linear, quadratic-quadratic and so on)?